# default navigation in custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development

can someone help me how to use the default(Top Navigation menu) in custom master page in sharepoint. i want to use the same Top Navigation as default master.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of default master page and customize that file. In that way you won't lose the top navigation panel.